# How to delete an object and all its children from DB in server using Breeze EFContextProvider?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I know how to do it in the client side...I have to loop through all the child entities and call entityAspect.setDeleted(). But how do I do it in the server from BreezeController? What is the equivalent on server using Breeze EFContextProvider?

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest choice would be to set up a cascade delete on the SQL Server database. You will still need to remove the children on the client after the save succeeds, but you won't need to do anything else on the server.

The other alternative is to actually fetch the children entities within your BeforeSaveEntities method ,add them to the save map and then delete them ( mark them as deleted in EF).

Comment: To your first suggestion, I tried it but it doesn't work. I remember I read somewhere that the old EF doesn't support cascase delete. Last weekend, I upgraded my EF from 5.0 to 6.1, but still not working. When I try to delete the parent entity without marking the children as deleted, I got the error like `The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.XXX_dbo.YYY`. However, when I delete the parent row from Visual Studio Database Explorer, the cascade delete is working fine. So, is there something I missed?

Comment: To your second suggestion, how do you `add them to the save map and then delete them`? I tried this approach, but got stuck.

Comment: A third approach would be a stored procedure or dynamic SQL, issued by EF with the `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(deleteSql)`. You probably want to do that within the same transaction. Fortunately, you can enlist this command in the same transaction that Breeze uses for your other saves. How?  I've not done it myself but I know people who have. Maybe there's documentation? Let Jay tell you :-).

Comment: The ["ContextProvider" documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider) describes both how to manipulate `OriginalValues` **and** create an umbrella transaction context.